# How i can push edited row in localstorage using js

Tags: javascript, html, object

I've been attempting to create an edit page for my local storage lists, but whenever I try to alter the current item, it changes the entire array instead of just the row that I changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')) || [];

const product = {
  id: 1,
  pName: 'Iphone 14 Pro Max',
  pNumber: 'Serial-C2',
  pColor: 'Deep Purple',
  plPrice: 4300,
  done: false,
  createdAt: new Date().toLocaleString('ka-GE')
}

    let pasucc = products.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));

    DisplayProducts();

    /*add object to localstorage*/
    products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')) || [];
    
    const addForm = document.querySelector('#add-form');
    
    addForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const pName = e.target.elements.pName.value;
    const pNumber = e.target.elements.pNumber.value;
    const pColor = e.target.elements.pColor.value;
    const plPrice = e.target.elements.plPrice.value;
    
    const product = {
    id: products.length + 1,
    pName: pName,
    pNumber: pNumber,
    pColor: pColor,
    plPrice: plPrice,
    done: false,
    createdAt: new Date().toLocaleString('ka-GE')
    }
    
    if (plPrice > 10000) {
    return toastr.warning('the field List Price must be between 1 and 10000');
    } else if (plPrice <= 0) {
    return toastr.warning('the field List Price must be between 1 and 10000');
    }
    
    let pasucc = products.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
    
    if (pasucc = true) {
    toastr.success('Product Added Successfuly !');
    }
    // Reset the form
    e.target.reset();
    
    });
    
    /*this is how i try to update current object in localstorage*/
    
    products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products')) || [];
    const clickedId = localStorage.getItem('clickedId') || '';
    const editForm = document.getElementById("edit-form");
    
    
    products.forEach(product => {
    if (clickedId == product.id) {
    editForm.innerHTML = `
    <input type="text" id="pName" class="form-control" value="${product.pName}" required>
    <input type="text" id="pNumber" class="form-control" value="${product.pNumber}" required>
    <input type="text" id="pColor" class="form-control" value="${product.pColor}" required>
    <input type="number" id="plPrice" class="form-control" value="${product.plPrice}">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-danger" >Go Back</a>
    `;
    }
    
    });
    
    
    products.forEach(product => {
    
    editForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const pNameVal = editForm["pName"];
    const pNumberVal = editForm["pNumber"];
    const pColorVal = editForm["pColor"];
    const plPriceVal = editForm["plPrice"];
    
    const pName = pNameVal.value;
    const pNumber = pNumberVal.value;
    const pColor = pColorVal.value;
    const plPrice = plPriceVal.value;
    
    var newProduct = {
    id: product.id,
    pName: pName,
    pNumber: pNumber,
    pColor: pColor,
    plPrice: plPrice,
    done: product.done,
    createdAt: product.createdAt
    }
    
    var updatedProducts = products.slice();
    updatedProducts.push(newProduct);
    
    localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(newProduct));
    });
    
    });
    
    });
```

```html
<div class="productform">
  <h2>Edit Product Form</h2>
  <form id="edit-form">   
  </form>
</div>
```

I attempted to include my code in a snippet, verify it, and see if anything needed to be changed. I had already set up auto-push to local storage to test how to alter it.

Comment: Next time please take time to make a simple reproducible example inside HTML/JS snippet or any other fiddle like jsfiddle.net, you can use simple array instead of localStorage that are usually forbidden in snippets

Answer (score 0):

You named your constant `products` while looping through the array also named `products`.

Instead of overwriting `products`, append with `product` array (id, name, number,...)

```js
var newProduct = {
    id: product.id,
    pName: pName1,
    pNumber: pNumber1,
    pColor: pColor1,
    plPrice: plPrice1,
    done: product.done,
    createdAt: product.createdAt
}

// create a new array so we do not modify the original array we are currently looping into
var updatedProducts = products.slice();
updatedProducts.push( newProduct );

localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(updatedProducts ));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i want to update current object which i get from products not to add new object after edit

Comment: Then add an hidden field  `productId` in the form so that we can retrieve and update it. I'll help you more if you edit your question with a working snippet :)

Comment: I tried to insert my code into the snippet, check it, if something need to change tell me i will try